# General reference questions

Tags: discussion

Can a question be too basic, too general, and should therefore be avoided? This is a [classical meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86043/introduce-a-general-reference-close-reason) of many Stack Exchange sites. E.g. would the following question be considered *General Reference* and be closed:

**What is the meaning and usage of the affix 'il' ?**

Let's follow the flowchart:

1. Web search finds result quickly? ==> **Yes**
2. The found answers need improvement? ==> **Yes and No**. The explanations may be a bit brief, and it can be hard to locate the particular answer on a long page.
3. If we go for No, we end up at the final decision point: Is it interesting? ==> **Yes**

Conclusion: Asking about a particular affix is a good question.

Here is a related question about [single word translations](https://esperanto.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163/do-we-allow-single-word-translations-that-can-be-looked-up-in-a-dictionary).

**Decision flowchart for interesting questions**

[image: Interesting question decision tree flowchart]

Comment: For the question used as example, if the question doesn't explain what exactly the OP doesn't understand, or what the OP read and found difficult to understand (or that contradicts what read somewhere else), the question could be closed.